# problems with sending a JavaScript value to a PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php

I have a modal view with some data. One of the pieces of data is ID, that I have from JavaScript in one field dd. I use this `document.getElementById('id').textContent` for viewing the number ID, but my problem is, that I need to send this value a PHP variable.

In some tutorials I've seen:

```
<?php
   $total = "<script>document.write(valorAveria)</script>";
   echo 'Total value is '.$total;
?>
```

But I haven't view any number.

Comment: Unfortunately this is an extremely dated tutorial you're using. If you want to do it the modern way, you will make a REST endpoint, and JavaScript will call it. Mixing PHP and javascript inline like this (and document.write) is old and bad practice.

Comment: PHP runs on the server, and javascript runs in the client browser. The life cycle of the first ends before the lifecycle of the 2nd begins. You can't do what you are trying to do here

Comment: You can no have php and javascirpt interact together. Basics of the page lifecycle. To send data from clientside to serverside it involves ajax/fetch, form submission, or websockets.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the tutorial you're reading is leading you astray.  The technique they describe simply won't work (anymore).

You need to find and read lots of tutorials on "AJAX" in the context of PHP.  This is a technique where you use JavaScript to send an *asynchronous* HTTP request to the PHP server, specifying a JavaScript function that will be called when the response data arrives.  So, this is how you notify the server that you want to update some value.

Like I said, find *recent* online tutorials on the subject of AJAX, and you will very quickly be on your way.

Comment: if you want them to find modern tutorials, let's not use the barely still used term "AJAX" and instead use the current term "restful API" as the name for the thing you need to implement on the PHP side, and "restful API endpoint" as the name for the thing JS talks to.